# How to use Green UML to reverse engineer java code

Tags: uml, reverse-engineering, tool-uml, green-uml

I found **Green UML**, a good UML tool that integrates well into Eclipse (and it is free)

I could develop a class disgram with it easily.

I am looking for a specific tutorial or help, which explains *how to reverse engineer existing java code*, into Class Diagrams, using **Green UML**.

Thanks.

Comment: There are better tools than Green UML, so kindly ignore this post